# Python IsInstance() for classes and subclasses

Tags: python, class, multiple-inheritance, python-decorators

This code is from python cook book 3rd edition from classes chapter section 8.13 . The program tries to define various kinds of data structures, but want to enforce constraints on the values that are allowed to be assigned to certain attributes.
I am executing the program in python 2.7 with Pycharm IDE.

```
# Base class. Uses a descriptor to set a value
class Descriptor(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None, **opts):
        self.name = name
        for key, value in opts.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value

# Descriptor for enforcing types
class Typed(Descriptor):
    expected_type = type(None)
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, self.expected_type):
            raise TypeError('expected ' + str(self.expected_type))
        super(Typed,self).__set__(instance, value)

class Integer(Typed):
    expected_type = int

class String(Typed):
    expected_type = str

class MaxSized(Descriptor):
    def __init__(self, name=None, **opts):
        if 'size' not in opts:
            raise TypeError('missing size option')
        super(MaxSized,self).__init__(name, **opts)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if len(value) >= self.size:
            raise ValueError('size must be < ' + str(self.size))
        super(MaxSized,self).__set__(instance, value)


class SizedString(String, MaxSized):
    pass

# Class decorator to apply constraints
def check_attributes(**kwargs):
    def decorate(cls):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            if isinstance(value, Descriptor):
                value.name = key
                setattr(cls, key, value)
            else:
                setattr(cls, key, value(key))
        return cls
    return decorate

# Example
@check_attributes(name=String,shares=Integer,place=SizedString('tester',size=8))
class Stock(object):
    def __init__(self, stkname, stkqty,stkhq):
        self.name = stkname
        self.shares = stkqty
        self.place = stkhq
```

when executing the code with the below initialization ,

```
s = Stock('ACME', 50,'hky')
print s.name # print ACME
print s.shares # prints 50
print s.place # prints hky
```

> Condition:

When debugging the below code for @check_attributes *place=SizedString('tester',size=8)*, the below **if** condition is True where as for *name=String and shares=Integer* , the else condition is True.

```
       if isinstance(value, Descriptor):
            value.name = key
            setattr(cls, key, value)
        else:
            setattr(cls, key, value(key))
```

> Questions :

1. If SizedString is an instance of Descriptor ( based on Inheritance hierarchy- String , Typed , MaxSized, Descriptor ), then String and Integer also should satisfy the If condition right ? because at the end it is also the subclass of ( typed , Descriptor ) ?

   2. What is value(key) in setattr(cls, key, value(key)) means , cant understand what is value(key ) means ?

Sorry for the lengthy context, but wanted to be clear as much as possible .

Comment: Why are you passing that dummy `'tester'` value in `SizedString('tester', size=8)` instead of just using `SizedString(size=8)`? Or, if you for some reason want to enforce temporary names that are just going to be overridden by `@check_attributes`, why allow `name=None`?

Comment: The title is calling out for `issubclass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. > If SizedString is an instance of Descriptor ( based on Inheritance hierarchy- String , Typed , MaxSized, Descriptor ), then String and Integer also should satisfy the If condition right ? because at the end it is also the subclass of ( typed , Descriptor ) ?

   We have to look carefully at what is being passed into the `check_attributes` function. Look closer at what the value of the `name` and `share` keyword arguments are:

   ```
   @check_attributes(name=String,shares=Integer,place=SizedString('tester',size=8))
   ```

   Notice the lack of parenthesis after the `String` and `Integer` class names? This means the `String` and `Integer` *class object themselves* are being passed into `check_attributes`, not an instance of either class. And since the `String` class object and the `Integer` class object are not sub-classes of `Descriptor`, `isinstance(value, Descriptor)` fails.
2. > What is value(key) in setattr(cls, key, value(key)) means , cant understand what is value(key ) means ?

   Think about it. Since `value` has the value of whatever keyword argument was passed into `check_attributes`, and the value is not an instance of the `Descriptor` class, then `value` must be referring to a class object. (If you don't understand why this is, refer back to my answer to your first question). So calling `value(key)` is creating an instance of some class, and passing in the `key` value as a constructor argument.

Comment: These explanations helped me.

Comment: Glad I could help out @Joe_12345!